# Ruby on Rails and Bundle install of wubook_wired app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml-parsing, xml-rpc

When I execute the command bundle, appears compilation errors that I dont
found a solution.

I work with os Windows 10 and the version of Ruby and Rails are:

ruby:
  bin:        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/ruby.exe
  version:    ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [i386-mingw32]

rails:
  bin:        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/rails.bat
  version:    Rails 4.1.8

The Gem that I intend to install on my  project is wubook_wired that is for WuBook API integration , called "Wired":
https://github.com/eilers/wubook_wired

The error that appear is:

```
    Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
    checking for expat.h... yes
    checking for XML_ParserCreate() in -lexpat... no
    checking for XML_ParserCreate() in -lxmltok... no
    *** extconf.rb failed ***
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
    libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
    need configuration options.

    Provided configuration options:
            --with-opt-dir
            --without-opt-dir
            --with-opt-include
            --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
            --with-opt-lib
            --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
            --with-make-prog
            --without-make-prog
            --srcdir=.
            --curdir
            --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby
            --with-perl-enc-map
            --without-perl-enc-map
            --with-expat-dir
            --without-expat-dir
            --with-expat-include
            --without-expat-include=${expat-dir}/include
            --with-expat-lib
            --without-expat-lib=${expat-dir}/lib
            --with-expatlib
            --without-expatlib
            --with-xmltoklib
            --without-xmltoklib

    extconf failed, exit code 1

    Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/xmlparser-0.7.2.1 for inspection.
    Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/xmlparser-0.7.2.1/gem_make.out
    An error occurred while installing xmlparser (0.7.2.1), and Bundler cannot
    continue.
    Make sure that `gem install xmlparser -v '0.7.2.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

The mkmf.log file is:

```
    have_library: checking for XML_ParserCreate() in -lexpat... -------------------- no

    "gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib -L.      -lmsvcrt-ruby210 -lexpat  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
    conftest.c: In function 't':
    conftest.c:16:57: error: 'XML_ParserCreate' undeclared (first use in this function)
    conftest.c:16:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
    conftest.c:16:32: warning: variable 'p' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
    checked program was:

        /* begin */
         1: #include "ruby.h"
         2: 
         3: #include 
         4: #include 
         5: 
         6: /*top*/
         7: extern int t(void);
         8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
         9: {
        10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
        11:     printf("%p", &t);
        12:   }
        13: 
        14:   return 0;
        15: }
        16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))XML_ParserCreate; return 0; }
        /* end */

    "gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib -L.      -lmsvcrt-ruby210 -lexpat  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
    conftest.c: In function 't':
    conftest.c:16:1: warning: implicit declaration of function 'XML_ParserCreate' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    c:/railsinstaller/devkit/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lexpat
    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    checked program was:

        /* begin */
         1: #include "ruby.h"
         2: 
         3: #include 
         4: #include 
         5: 
         6: /*top*/
         7: extern int t(void);
         8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
         9: {
        10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
        11:     printf("%p", &t);
        12:   }
        13: 
        14:   return 0;
        15: }
        16: int t(void) { XML_ParserCreate(); return 0; }
        /* end */

    --------------------

    have_library: checking for XML_ParserCreate() in -lxmltok... -------------------- no


    "gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib -L.      -lmsvcrt-ruby210 -lxmltok  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
    conftest.c: In function 't':
    conftest.c:16:57: error: 'XML_ParserCreate' undeclared (first use in this function)
    conftest.c:16:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
    conftest.c:16:32: warning: variable 'p' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
    checked program was:

        /* begin */
        1: #include "ruby.h"
        2: 
        3: #include 
        4: #include 
        5: 
        6: /*top*/
        7: extern int t(void);
        8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
        9: {
        10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
        11:     printf("%p", &t);
        12:   }
        13: 
        14:   return 0;
        15: }
        16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))
        XML_ParserCreate; return 0; }
        /* end */


    "gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib -L.      -lmsvcrt-ruby210 -lxmltok  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
    conftest.c: In function 't':
    conftest.c:16:1: warning: implicit declaration of function 'XML_ParserCreate' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    c:/railsinstaller/devkit/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lxmltok
    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    checked program was:

        /* begin */
         1: #include "ruby.h"
         2: 
         3: #include 
         4: #include 
         5: 
         6: /*top*/
         7: extern int t(void);
         8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
         9: {
        10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
        11:     printf("%p", &t);
        12:   }
        13: 
        14:   return 0;
        15: }
        16: int t(void) { XML_ParserCreate(); return 0; }
        /* end */
```

I would be very grateful for a help.

Answer (score 0):

I did the next steps for solution:

Because  I don't found the libexpat.a in the Devkit folder (c:\RailsInstaller\DevKit):
The text  "./i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lexpat"  means a reference the  libexpat.a file.

I download the mingw-w64-install.exe and then I install it.

Next I run command bundle but not yet correct.

Later I copy the libexpat.a file from the "C:\Program Files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-5.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v4-rev0\mingw32\opt\lib" folder where the mingw-w64 is  installed, to the "C:\RailsInstaller\DevKit\mingw\i686-w64-mingw32\lib" folder.

And "Eureka": The command bundle running ok.

Thats all.

Please if anyone has a better solution.....